# Jenkinsfile Dockerfile binding volume pwd

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins is running in a docker container (this works). In a job using a Jenkinsfile I am trying to bind a volume to the current working directory in Jenkins to a path in the job container, however I am failing to get the value of the current working directory to work. I've tried env.WORKSPACE and pwd() but the job errors out. How should I be declaring the equivalent of **-v $(pwd):/workdir**? And how would I add additional volumes?

My **Dockerfile.job** is simply:

```
FROM crops/poky:ubuntu-18.04

RUN /bin/bash -c 'echo La la la'

ENV myblah="my blah variable" \
    otherblah="this is another bla variable"
    
ADD entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

The **Jenkinsfile** stage that is giving me grief is something like this:

```
stage('this problematic stage') {
    agent {
       dockerfile {
           filename 'Dockerfile.job'
           args "-v ${pwd()}:/workdir"  // <- help! this doesn't work
      }
    }
    steps {
      // this works fine if I comment out my args above
      echo "yoohoo"
      sh 'echo myblah = $myblah'
      sh 'echo otherblah = $otherblah' 
}
```

For the curious **entrypoint.sh** is a copy paste from JENKINS bug 51307

```
!/bin/sh
# Workaround script for Jenkins bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51307
set -e

# check if there was a command passed
# required by Jenkins Docker plugin: https://github.com/docker-library/official-images#consistency
if [ "$1" ]; then
    # execute it
    exec "$@"
fi

# else run my script
exec ls -la
```

Comment: Docker agents in Jenkins Pipeline already have the workspace directory automatically bind volume mounted to the container. What are you trying to do additionally here?

Comment: ok but how would I bind an additional directory say -v $(pwd)/some/where:/var/some/where ?

Comment: Have you tried using the `${WORKSPACE}` variable?

Comment: @foo0x29a ${WORKSPACE} also errors out with: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: WORKSPACE for class: groovy.lang.Binding